# Sending uint8array with axios

Tags: javascript, axios

I'm trying to send a uint8arrray to an endpoint. The post request gets send as these weird characters, for example: }Û²¤:åûDÌ¿p¿

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => zlib.gzip(upload, (err, buffer) => {
    if (err) {
      return reject('An error occured');
    }

    return axios.post(endpoint, buffer, {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'text/plain',
        'Content-Encoding': 'gzip',
      },
    })
    .then(response => resolve(response))
    .catch(error => error && reject(error.response.data.description))
  }));
```

Thanks

Comment: Those characters are binary interpreted as `text/plain`. Use `application/octet-stream` instead.

Comment: I changed it to `application/octet-stream` and I still see in the browser request payload that it is the strange chars

Comment: That might just be the result of the browser inspector forcing binary into plaintext for display. Can the server receive the gzip payload and unzip without problem?

Comment: You're right, thanks